# Spring Boot Application with Eureka on CloudFoundry healthcheck failed issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring Boot Application (standalone jar file) which I am try to deploy on CloudFoundry. I created one Service Registry instance on CloudFoundry and trying to push `(cf push -p target\microservice-user-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)` my application **(user-service)** using CloudFoundry CLI.

It uploads application successfully and also service binding happen successfully. Once it start, it gives health check failed issue

```
2016-06-21T16:13:13.79-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.79-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG WebappClassLoaderBase -     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.79-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG WebappClassLoaderBase -     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.79-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG WebappClassLoaderBase -     findClass(org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBeanCustomizer)
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.79-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG WebappClassLoaderBase -     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.79-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG WebappClassLoaderBase -     findClass(org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxyCustomizer)
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.79-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG WebappClassLoaderBase -     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG DelegatingFilterProxy - Filter 'springSecurityFilterChain' configured successfully
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG Registry - Managed= Tomcat:j2eeType=Filter,WebModule=//localhost/,name=springSecurityFilterChain,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none                                                                                                                                                2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG BaseModelMBean - preRegister ApplicationFilterConfig[name=springSecurityFilterChain, filterClass=org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy] Tomcat:j2eeType=Filter,WebModule=//localhost/,name=springSecurityFilterChain,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG [/] -  Starting filter 'webRequestLoggingFilter'                                                               2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG Registry - Managed= Tomcat:j2eeType=Filter,WebModule=//localhost/,name=webRequestLoggingFilter,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG BaseModelMBean - preRegister ApplicationFilterConfig[name=webRequestLoggingFilter, filterClass=org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter] Tomcat:j2eeType=Filter,WebModule=//localhost/,name=webRequestLoggingFilter,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG StandardContext - Starting completed
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]] to [INITIALIZING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]] to [INITIALIZED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost]] to [INITIALIZING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG Registry - Managed= Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,name=ErrorReportValve
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG BaseModelMBean - preRegister org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost] Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,name=ErrorReportValve
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost]] to [INITIALIZED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost]] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost]] to [INITIALIZING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG Registry - Managed= Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,name=StandardHostValve
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG BaseModelMBean - preRegister org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost] Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,name=StandardHostValve
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost]] to [INITIALIZED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost]] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] to [INITIALIZING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] to [INITIALIZED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat]] to [INITIALIZING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG Registry - Managed= Tomcat:type=Valve,name=StandardEngineValve
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG BaseModelMBean - preRegister org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat] Tomcat:type=Valve,name=StandardEngineValve
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat]] to [INITIALIZED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat]] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat]] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener@1c7c9651] to [STARTING_PREP]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener@1c7c9651] to [STARTING]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG Mapper - Registered host [localhost]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG MapperListener - Register Wrapper [default] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG MapperListener - Register Wrapper [dispatcherServlet] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG MapperListener - Register Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG MapperListener - Register host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener@1c7c9651] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [StandardService[Tomcat]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LifecycleBase - Setting state for [StandardServer[-1]] to [STARTED]
    2016-06-21T16:13:13.80-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.18-0400 [HEALTH/0]   OUT healthcheck failed
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.18-0400 [HEALTH/0]   OUT Exit status 1
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.50-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LoggingRestTemplate - Created GET request for "https://api.run.pivotal.io/info"
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.50-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG LoggingRestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.51-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.52-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.52-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api.run.pivotal.io:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.54-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.run.pivotal.io:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.54-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://api.run.pivotal.io:443
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.54-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to api.run.pivotal.io/52.72.101.87:443
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.54-0400 [APP/0]      OUT 16: DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to api.run.pivotal.io/52.72.101.87:443 with timeout 0
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.70-0400 [HEALTH/0]   OUT healthcheck failed
    2016-06-21T16:13:14.70-0400 [HEALTH/0]   OUT Exit status 1
    2016-06-21T16:13:15.74-0400 [HEALTH/0]   OUT healthcheck failed
```

This is the link of my [user-service](https://github.com/anz2050/microservice-user-service) application in Github.

Below is the content of my **application.yml** file:

```
# Spring properties
spring:
  application:
     name: ${vcap.application.name}
  cloud:
    services:
      registrationMethod: route 

---

spring:
  profiles: dev

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false

# Logging
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

This is my **manifest.yml** file:

```
instances: 1 
memory: 1024M 
applications: 
   - name: user-service 
     services: 
       - my-eureka-server 
     env: 
       SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
```

The **pom.xml** file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.verizon.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice-user-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>microservice-user-service</name>
    <description>Demo project Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent> 

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

     <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository> 
            <id>spring-release</id> 
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url> 
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Anyone can help me what I am missing. I tried to find the solution everywhere, but couldn't get it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running on JDK 8 and Tomcat 8?

Comment: It feels like your application has failed start-up, can you look through your logs once more, turning down the log level may help a little more - `logging.level.root = DEBUG`

Comment: yeah, I am using JDK 8 and Tomcat 8. Tomcat instance is created automatically by Spring Boot starter pom.

Comment: Just checking with root log level to DEBUG

Comment: I updated the logs with 'logging.level.root = DEBUG'.  But the reason is not much clear or may be I am not able to understand.

Comment: I see a call using `LoggingRestTemplate` to `https://api.run.pivotal.io/info` - can you please help with where that call is coming from, were you by any change using a snapshot version of one of the libraries

Comment: Right now, I am using only 'spring-milestones' and 'spring-release' repository. You may refer my 'pom.xml, file. I am also not sure, how the RestTemplate call is happening for this URL and even my URL is different (company custom URL) not this 'https://api.run.pivotal.io/info'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue, now. I was missing CloudFoundry PORT environment variable in the application.yml file.

This [link](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html#start) explain the issue.

Now, the **application.yml** file looks like as belwo:

```
# HTTP Server
server:
  port: ${vcap.PORT}

# Spring properties
spring:
  application:
     name: ${vcap.application.name}
  cloud:
    services:
      registrationMethod: route 

---

spring:
  profiles: dev
---
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false

---

# Logging
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
```

Now, my application is up and running on Cloud Foundry. I am able to access the services using the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with POM configuration.

Can you please set the DOMAIN and HOST name while pushing this app? The below error had health check is failure is due to this:

```
Register host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
```